# Error " The getter 'userID' isn't defined for the type 'Response'. "in flutter

Tags: flutter

In my code has a textfield in there can type name then click button  that should pass to http URL and then should get "userID" from that URL.

**button code**

```
 Future<void> onJoin() async {
    setState(() {
      myController.text.isEmpty
          ? _validateError = true
          : _validateError = false;
    });



    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => loadData(myController.text)),
    );
  }
```

**get "userID" from http url**

```
  loadData(String myController) async {
    var userID = "";
    try {
      final uri =
          Uri.parse('http://github.users.com/$myController');
      final response = await http.get(uri);

      if (response.userID != null) {
        print("userID : " + userID);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Invalid name entered ");
    }
  }
```

If successfully retrieve userId then that should print if it null then should display "Invalid name entered ".

**Error**

[image]

Comment: You should assign a class type to the response, you have declare it as a final.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
final response = await http.get(uri);

final Map<String, dynamic> data = response.body;

if (data["userID"] != null) {
  print("userID : " + data["userID"]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help bro at the "final Map<String, dynamic> data = response.body;" show this error " A value of type 'String' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'. (Documentation)  Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'Map<String, dynamic>'"

Comment: I edited the question and I added that image

Comment: change to final Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(response.body);

Answer (score 1):

**response.body** is an encoded json thats why you are getting

```
 A value of type 'String' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<String, dynamic>
```

so decode your response body, as below

```
final Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(response.body);
```